# Kotlin - Broadcast Receiver for SmsReceiver issue in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am using Broadcast Receive as below :

```
private val mSmsReceiver=SmsReceiver()

/*
* Default Activity life cycle method which registers Broadcast receiver named
* SmsReceiver for the intent filter SMS_RECEIVED.
* */
public override fun onResume() {
    LogUtil.e("<<< onResume MESSAGE", "RECEIVED")
    //if(PermissionUtil.hasPermissions(this@OTPUtilityActivity,READ_SMS)){
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        mSmsReceiver,
        IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")
    )
    super.onResume()
}
```

I am registering it as above.

Now, I am unregistered it as below when I got success in my web service:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mSmsReceiver)
```

And yes, I have taken tag for it in manifest as below :

```
    <receiver android:name=".ui.core.broadcast_receiver.SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The **Issue** is, Broadcast receiver's method also called when I have navigated to another screen on success of my service after unregistering receiver.
It's calling when any new message received which should not call since I have unregistered it.

**How can I completely unregister it**, so that it never call again when any sms receives in device ?

Note : I have tried removing receiver from Manifest. But, with that I can't receive a singal message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the intent filter from manifest. If you register, unregister from code, that's not necessary. As it would continue to listen to that broadcast at app level.

Comment: I just have to remove the <intent-filter> from the <receiver> or whole <receiver> ?